# Using replace() in Postgres

Tags: postgresql

This query works:

```
SELECT replace('hello world','world','andrew');
```

Output:

```
   replace    
--------------
 hello andrew
(1 row)
```

But this does not:

```
SELECT replace(geo,',',' ') FROM image_meta ;
ERROR:  function replace(point, unknown, unknown) does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT replace(geo,',',' ') FROM image_meta ;
               ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

(non-working example was initially posted incorrectly; this one is correct).

The data type of "geo" is `POINT`.

Comment: What is the structure of your table? The error message states that the column does not exist. Are you sure that there aren't have any typos in your table structure definition?

Comment: Does the column full_caption exist in table image_meta?

Comment: I pasted the wrong example of the code not working previously; this is the correct one. The data type is point. Points are recorded with commas separating the numbers; I am trying to convert to postGIS data types, which uses spaces instead of commas. Any way I can convert this text into a string so I can replace the comma?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, you can query the individual arguments of a `POINT` data type, so

```
select geo[0],geo[1] from image_meta limit 1;
```

returns the individual x,y values of the point so I can convert them to a geometry data type for postGIS.

The query I used to update the entire database was

`update image_meta SET geom=st_geographyfromtext('SRID=4326;POINT(' || geo[0] || ' ' || geo[1] || ')');`

Comment: Rather than handling it as text, why not do this: `st_setsrid(st_point(geo[0], geo[1]), 4326)::geography`? Also, you say '... to a geometry data type', but you're using geography. These data types are different, to remove ambiguity.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ST_AsText(geo) FROM image_meta;
```

would also give you the geometry as text. With this you could use replace.